# Classification for machine learning

Tags: classification

Is there any way to classify a data that looks like this with 10 different classes? is there any preprocessing required to make the data more separable to enhance the classification accuracy[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avrHr.jpg)?

Answer (score 0):

SVM and logistic regression can deal better with multi-classification. 
Data Recommendation:
(If I am dealing with your data: I don't see there is much evidence to classify them into 10 categories, would recommend grouping the categories of the dependent variable into three or four at least that might help to a user instead of the wrong classification )